# Trouble converting custom CGRect function from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, cgrect

I've been going back and forth on trying to convert a custom `CGRect` function from `Objective-C` to `Swift`.

I'll make some small progress but then I always end up getting stuck. Here is the working function in `Objective-C`:

```
CGRect CGRectSmallestWithCGPoints(NSMutableArray *pointsArray, int numberOfPoints) {

NSValue *firstValue = pointsArray[0];

CGFloat greatestXValue = [firstValue CGPointValue].x;
CGFloat greatestYValue = [firstValue CGPointValue].y;
CGFloat smallestXValue = [firstValue CGPointValue].x;
CGFloat smallestYValue = [firstValue CGPointValue].y;

for(int i = 1; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
    NSValue *value = pointsArray[i];

    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    greatestXValue = MAX(greatestXValue, point.x);
    greatestYValue = MAX(greatestYValue, point.y);
    smallestXValue = MIN(smallestXValue, point.x);
    smallestYValue = MIN(smallestYValue, point.y);
}

CGRect rect;

rect.origin = CGPointMake(smallestXValue, smallestYValue);
rect.size.width = greatestXValue - smallestXValue;
rect.size.height = greatestYValue - smallestYValue;

  return rect;
}
```

Here's where I currently am with the `Swift` conversion:

```
func CGRectSmallestWithCGPoints(pointsArray: NSArray, numberOfPoints: Int) -> CGRect {

    var greatestXValue = pointsArray[0].x
    var greatestYValue = pointsArray[0].y
    var smallestXValue = pointsArray[0].x
    var smallestYValue = pointsArray[0].y

    for(var i = 1; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        let point = pointsArray[i];

        greatestXValue = max(greatestXValue, point.x);
        greatestYValue = max(greatestYValue, point.y);
        smallestXValue = min(smallestXValue, point.x);
        smallestYValue = min(smallestYValue, point.y);
    }

    var rect = CGRect()
    rect.origin = CGPointMake(smallestXValue, smallestYValue);
    rect.size.width = greatestXValue - smallestXValue;
    rect.size.height = greatestYValue - smallestYValue;

    return rect;
}
```

The errors start in the for loop. When I try to use max and min it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'CLHeadingComponentValue' (aka 'Double') to a value of type 'CLHeadingComponentValue!'
```

And then after the for loop when I modify the `rect` values it gives me a similar error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'CLHeadingComponentValue' (aka 'Double') to a value of type 'CGFloat'
```

I'm having trouble understanding why this conversion seems so hard. I've been using Swift on and off for the past few weeks now and I've gotten stuck on certain things like some of the `optional` concepts but never been stuck on something for this long before.

I'm using Xcode 7 beta with Swift 2 and would really appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code, you have to use the `CGPointValue` property instead of the `x` property directly see the fixed code:

```
func CGRectSmallestWithCGPoints(pointsArray: NSArray, numberOfPoints: Int) -> CGRect {

    var greatestXValue: CGFloat = pointsArray[0].CGPointValue.x
    var greatestYValue: CGFloat = pointsArray[0].CGPointValue.y
    var smallestXValue: CGFloat = pointsArray[0].CGPointValue.x
    var smallestYValue: CGFloat = pointsArray[0].CGPointValue.y

    for(var i = 1; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {

       let point = pointsArray[i].CGPointValue

       greatestXValue = max(greatestXValue, point.x)
       greatestYValue = max(greatestYValue, point.y)
       smallestXValue = min(smallestXValue, point.x)
       smallestYValue = min(smallestYValue, point.y)
    }

    var rect = CGRect()
    rect.origin = CGPointMake(smallestXValue, smallestYValue);
    rect.size.width = greatestXValue - smallestXValue;
    rect.size.height = greatestYValue - smallestYValue;

    return rect
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! Just for clarity though, when we first define smallestYValue it should be using the CGPoint's y value, not the x.

Comment: No worries just thought I'd mention. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A more functional approach:

```
func CGRectSmallestWithCGPoints(pointsArray: [CGPoint]) -> CGRect? {
    if pointsArray.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }

    let minX = pointsArray.reduce(CGFloat.max) { min, point in min(min, point.x) }
    let minY = pointsArray.reduce(CGFloat.max) { min, point in min(min, point.y) }
    let maxX = pointsArray.reduce(CGFloat.min) { max, point in max(max, point.x) }
    let maxY = pointsArray.reduce(CGFloat.min) { max, point in max(max, point.y) }

    let rect = CGRect(x: minX, y: minY, width: maxX - minX, height: maxY - minY)
    return rect
}
```